# Why `lein uberjar` evaluates variables defined with `def`?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I'm trying to understand "Lieningen" behaviour when creating an `uberjar`. Following is the minimal example which reproduces the behaviour:

```
(ns my-stuff.core
  (:gen-class))

(def some-var (throw (Exception. "boom!")))

(defn -main [& args]
  (println some-var))
```

When this is executed with `lein run` it clearly fails with an Exception. However, I don't understand why executing `lein uberjar` also fails with an Exception from variable definition? Why executing `lein uberjar` attempts to evaluate the variable value? Is this speecific to `uberjar` task or am I missing something more substantial about Clojure or Leiningen?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In order to compile your namespace for the uberjar (if you have AOT turned on), the clojure compiler must load your namespace. This will always invoke all top-level side effects.

The best way to handle this is to never have side effects in top level code (whether inside or outside a `def` form), and have initialization functions to realize any start-up side effects needed.

A workaround can be to make a small namespace that uses introspection to load the rest of your code at runtime but not while compiling - using a function like this:

```
(defn -main
  []
  (require 'my.primary.ns)
  ((resolve 'my.primary.ns/start)))
```

if that namespace is compiled, the jvm can find -main and run it, despite none of your other code being compiled. The runtime `require` will cause the Clojure compiler to load the rest of your code at runtime only, and `resolve` is needed so that `-main` will compile cleanly - it returns the var referenced, which then invokes your function when called.