# Clojure macros weirdness when running jars

Tags: clojure, macros, leiningen, uberjar

Below is a simple Clojure app example created with `lein new mw`:

```
(ns mw.core
  (:gen-class))

(def fs (atom {}))

(defmacro op []
  (swap! fs assoc :macro-f "somevalue"))

(op)

(defn -main [& args]
  (println @fs))
```

and in `project.clj` I have

```
:profiles {:uberjar {:aot [mw.core]}}
:main mw.core
```

When run in REPL, evaluating `@fs` returns `{:macro-f somevalue}`. But, running an uberjar yields `{}`. If I change `op` definition to `defn` instead of `defmacro`, then `fs` has again proper content when run from an uberjar. Why is that?

I vaguely realize that this has something to do with AOT compilation and the fact that macro-expansion occurs before the compilation phase, but clearly my understanding of these things is lacking.

I ran into this issue while trying to deploy an application that uses a very nice [mixfix](https://github.com/awto/mixfix-clj) library, in which mixfix operators are defined using a global atom. It took me quite a long time to isolate the issue to the example presented above.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: macros are used to modify "clojure-source-code" during compile time. since `op` has no input to modify, I ask you - what, in your opinion, should `op` do ? macros (since they "run" at compile time) are nonexistant in java bytecode / class files. EDIT: macros that capture or produce "stuff from/into outside scope" are also called non-hygenic macros and are especially fiddly to deal with.

Comment: Impure macro is a very evil thing. Though, probably you just forgot to quote it with backquote ` character.

Comment: @leonid-beschastny - I tried to reflect the behaviour used by mixfix with its `op` macro.

Comment: @birdspider - thanks for explaining what non-hygienic macros are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed related to the AOT, and the fact that some side effects are expected when a top-level code is executed - here at macro expansion time. The difference between the `lein repl` (or `lein run`) and the uberjar is in **when** exactly this happens.

When `lein repl` is executed, REPL starts and then loads the `mw.core` namespace automatically, if it is defined in `project.clj`, or one does it manually. When namespace is loaded, first the atom is defined, then macro is expanded and this expansion changes the value of the atom. All this happens in same runtime environment (in REPL process), and after the module is loaded, atom has an updated value in this REPL. Executing `lein run` will do pretty much the same - load namespace and then execute `-main` function in the same process.

And when `lein uberjar` is executed - same thing happens and this is the problem now. Compiler, in order to compile the `clj` file will first load it and evaluate the top level (I learned it myself from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32288353/302343)). So the module is loaded, top level is evaluated, **macro is expanded**, reference value is changed and then, after compilation completes, the compiler process, the one where reference value just changed, ends. Now, when the uberjar is executed with `java -jar` this spawns the new process, with a compiled code, where the macro is already expended (so `(op)` is already "replaced" with the code the `op` macro generated, which is none in this case). Therefore, atom value is unchanged.

In my opinion, *good fix would be to not rely on side effects in a macro*.

If stick to the macro anyway, the way to make this idea work is to skip the AOT for the module where macro expansion happens **and** load it lazily from the main module (again, same solution as in the other [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32288353/302343) I mentioned). For example:

`project.clj`:

```
; ...
:profiles {:uberjar {:aot [mw.main]}}) ; note, no `mw.core` here
; ...
```

`main.clj`:

```
(ns mw.main
  (:gen-class))

(defn get-fs []
  (require 'mw.core)
  @(resolve 'mw.core/fs))

(defn -main [& args]
  (println @(get-fs)))
```

`core.clj`:

```
(ns mw.core
  (:gen-class))

(def fs (atom {}))

(defmacro op []
  (swap! fs assoc :macro-f "somevalue"))

(op)
```

I'm not sure myself, however, if this solution is stable enough and that there are no edge cases. It does work though on this simple example.

Comment: thank you, `require` does work with uberjar, just tried it in the context of my original project. I agree that it is a bit hacky though.

Comment: I will mark this answer as accepted since it is the approach i've chosen to follow for now. Leonid's answer is excellent as well, so upvoting both:)

Answer (score 6):

The real problem here is that your macro is incorrect. You forgot to add backquote character:

```clj
(defmacro op []
  `(swap! fs assoc :macro-f "somevalue"))
; ^ syntax-quote ("backquote")
```

This operation is called syntax-quote and it's very important here, because macros in clojure modify your code during its compilation.

So, as a result you've got an impure macro, modifying `fs` atom whenever your code is **compiled**.

Since your macro doesn't produce any code, `(op)` call in your example does nothing at all (only it's **compilation** do). It appear to be working in REPL because compilation and execution is handled by the same clojure instance (see [**Timur**'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33217451/1202461) for details).

Comment: Thank you - yes, quoting the macro yields desired behaviour. I've contacted library maintainer to see if this can be amended (as I might be missing something in the library design).

Comment: And thanks for underscoring a difference between compilation and execution.