# Environment variables used in `def` statements in Clojure

Tags: clojure, environment-variables, leiningen

I have this piece of code:

```
(def heavy_computation (f1 (env :var1)))
```

where `(env :var1)` is fetching environment variable `VAR1` (with the help of [environ](https://github.com/weavejester/environ)) that points to a directory location and `f1` is a wrapper around Java function. This is used later in functions and it is heavy computation that I would like to compute just once.

I want to be able to customize `VAR1` and print an error message if it is missing in production.

If I compile this code `lein uberjar` without environment variables, it throws an error about `NullPointerException` at this line.

I can compile it with environmental variables and later if I set them appropriately, it will work. In order to print my error message in case it is missing, I have to put the code that checks it right before the `def` statement, otherwise it throws null pointer exception.

Can I do it in a cleaner way? I don't want to set environment variables in order to compile it and I want to put the code that performs checks in the `-main` function right before it starts the server.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32288195

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option is to wrap the evaluation in a [`delay`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/delay):

```
(def heavy-computation (delay (f1 (env :var1))))
```

Then wherever you need the result, you can `deref`/`@` the delay:

```
(when (= :ok @heavy-computation)
  (println "heavy!"))
```

The `delay`'s body will only be evaluated once, and not until you dereference it.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap the environment value in an if-let and handle the else branch with printing a warning. During compilation you will see the warning, but that would be OK with me personally. You can also use a memoized function instead of a delay to defer the computation.